# Using htaccess to change url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change a url like:

[dynamicdomain.com/mypage](http://dynamicdomain.com/mypage)

to

[dynamicdomain.com/mydashboard](http://dynamicdomain.com/mydashboard)

I want to display the content of `mypage` but the url that the users will see on the browser will contain `mydashboard`. How do I do this using `.htaccess`.

I tried using this:

`RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /mydashboard /mypage`

but this redirects the url:

`dynamicdomain.com/mydashboard`

to

`dynamicdomain.com/mypage`

**Edit:**
Here is another example on what I want to achieve:
I have a folder `mypage` which can be accessed as:
http://dynamicdomain.com/mypage/

I want the users to see http://dynamicdomain.com/mydashboard/
(`mydashboard` folder doesn't exists) when they access http://dynamicdomain.com/mypage/

can someone point me in the right direction.
Thanks.

Comment: Just mention me if you still need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these directives:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mypage$ /dashbord [NC,L]
```

Redirect directive does an external redirect *(redirects a URL to another URL)*. To redirect *"dashboard"* internally to *"/mypage"*, you need to use the `RewriteRule` directive of the Rewrite module.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this redirects  `/dashboard` to `/mypage`, which I don't want to do, I want to execute `/dashboard` but in the browser the users will see the url `/mypage`

Comment: Clear your browser's cache, and try this again.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your htaccess file :
just after IfModule closes

Redirect 301 /mypage  http://www.dynamicdomain.com/mydashboard

This will work for you.

thanks

Comment: this redirects `/mypage` to `mydashboard`, I want to execute `/mypage` but the users will see `/mydashboard` on the browser.

Comment: you can use the content of /mypage to/mydashboard. Why to make just a illusion.